# Serializing multiple List<T> objects in to the same XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Hello everyone I have three lists containing objects from the same class.
For example, here are my lists:

```
    List<Course> courselvl4 = new List<Course>();
    List<Course> courselvl5 = new List<Course>();
    List<Course> courselvl6 = new List<Course>();
```

I was wondering if it is possible, to serialize each of these lists in to the same XML file and deserialize back in to the lists. Thanks.
I have tried looking for the answer, but can not find it anywhere.
Please direct if answered already.

Comment: You may try to serialize `courselvl4.Union(courselvl5).Union(courselvl6)` Result of Union in your case would be of type IEnumerable<Course>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for this if you want to initialize your list with the proper capacity:

```
Int32 capacity = courselvl4.Count + courselvl5.Count + courselvl6.Count;

List<Course> courses = new List<Course>(capacity);
courses.AddRange(courselvl4);
courses.AddRange(courselvl5);
courses.AddRange(courselvl6);
```

Alternatively:

```
List<Course> courses = courselvl4
                 .Concat(courselvl5)
                 .Concat(courselvl6)
                 .ToList();
```

Then just go for:

```
SerializeCourses("CoursesList",courses);

private static XDocument SerializeCourses(String rootElement, List<Course> courses)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();

    using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter())
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(rootElement);

        foreach (Course course in courses)
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(Course)).Serialize(writer, course);

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Comment: no way did not think of that! Would you be able to de-serialize it back in to the seperate lists?

Comment: You have to serialize the courses level too so you can deserialize everything and then use GroupBy level to split them.

Comment: If my answer helped you in solving your problem, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry been trying to implement it, thanks for your help!